# Laravel Migration Error Syntax

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I am trying to migrate(update) this, but I keep getting this error message:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] syntax error,
>   unexpected '>', expecting '<'

```
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table)) {
        $table->string('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->string('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->string('XXXX', 10)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 100)->change();;
        $table->String('XXXX', 100)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 100)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->tinyInteger('XXXX')->unsigned()->change();
        $table->tinyInteger('XXXX')->unsigned()->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 100)->change();
        $table->tinyInteger('XXXX')->unsigned()->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->boolean('XXXX')->change();
        $table->boolean('XXXX')->change();
        $table->boolean('XXXX')->change();
        $table->boolean('XXXX')->change();
        $table->boolean('XXXX')->change();
        $table->boolean('XXXX')->change();
        $table->boolean('XXXX')->change();
        $table->boolean('XXXX')->change();
        $table->boolean('XXXX')->change();
        $table->text('XXXX')->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 100)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 100)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 100)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 100)->change();
        $table->tinyInteger('XXXX')->unsigned()->change();
        $table->tinyInteger('XXXX')->unsigned()->change();
        $table->tinyInteger('XXXX')->unsigned()->change();
        $table->tinyInteger('XXXX')->unsigned()->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();
        $table->text('XXXX');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: What line number? Are you sure it's in this block?

Answer (score 1):

You have `;;` in 5th line and also `String` instead of `string`.

By the way, when you run `migrate` command you can get error from some another file (controller, middleware, helper etc).

Answer (score 0):

In [Laravel Migration Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations), it said that using `$table->string('XXXX',50);` to create `VARCHAR` equivalent column.

So you have syntax errors with the statement `$table->String('XXXX', 50)->change();`. You should change all the `String` into `string`.

**PS**: Actually in the statement `$table->String('XXXX', 100)->change();;`.you have used `;;`, but it does not matter, **no errors** will be reported.